# How do I get Code coverage when using mjs and mocha delay?

Tags: mocha.js, istanbul, ecma

My code looks like this...

```
//suite.js
async function wire(){
    await import("./Sanity.spec.mjs"); // eslint-disable-line
    run();
}
wire();

// Sanity.spec.mjs
import chai from "chai";

describe("My Test", ()=>{
    it("Should do what I want",
        ()=>chai.assert.equal(1,1, "One is in fact 1")); // eslint-disable-line no-self-compare
});
```

I set my NODE_OPTIONS to `--experimental-modules` then I run the npm script `mocha --delay --exit ./test/suite.js` and this runs great. The problem is I can't figure out how to add code coverage. If I change the script to `nyc mocha --delay --exit ./test/suite.js` The results come back empty...

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

If I try to add @std/esm like suggested other places like this `nyc -r @std/esm mocha --delay --exit ./test/suite.js` I get the same thing. How do I get proper code coverage?

**I would like to point out all though this is a sanity test in my real suite I have multiple other tests that do in fact test the libraries classes,etc and should show coverage**